# Getting variable jQuery -> PHP (not working)

Tags: php, jquery, variables

I'm having problems with passing variables from jQuery into PHP. I search for the solutions on the internet, and i came to the AJAX. Never used Ajax before, so i guess that the problem is known.

So i have the following code in "index.php"

```
$("#inviteForm").submit(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
var emailVal = $("#email").val();

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "processAjax.php",
 data: {email: emailVal},
 success: function(data) {
    alert(data);  
}
});
});
```

In form, i have one input box (for email) and a submit button (the method is POST).

In processAjax.php i have the following code

```
<?php
    $x = $_POST['email'];
    return $x;
?>
```

So if i'm correct, if the $.ajax function is OK, the alert box should pop up. But it doesn't.
i've also tried alert(x); but it didn't work.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong

Comment: The absolute first thing I'd check is whether the AJAX request is actually being sent. Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) (for Firefox) or the Developer Tools in other browsers to do that (all accessed by hitting the F12 key). If it's not, you're probably trying to bind the `submit` event handler too early (before the form exists); if that's the case take a look at the [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

Comment: You don't return the value, you output it; as if you were outputting it to the user. Everything that is output on the page will be accessible through the `data` variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `echo $x;` instead of `return $x;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $x = $_POST['email'];
    echo $x;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for better data manipulation. Use json_encode from the server side and json datatype to your ajax calls. Then to alert server response, just alert the key of the array like alert(data.value):

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "processAjax.php",
 data: {email: emailVal},
 dataType: 'json'
 success: function(data) {
    alert(data.value);  
}
```

processAjax.php

```
$result['value'] = $_POST['email'];
echo json_encode($result);
```